# Need to sort array based on alphabetically and based on Upper and followed by lower case

Tags: arrays, swift, string, sorting

```
var names = [ "Alpha","alpha1","Alpha1","alpha2", "beta","Beta1"]
var sortedNames = names.sorted { $0.localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare($1) == ComparisonResult.orderedAscending }
```

I tried to sort the above array but not able to get what i want. Need the array to be sorted like below, can anyone please help on this to implement.

Need Output like below-:

```
[ "Alpha","Alpha1", "alpha1","alpha2", "Beta1","beta"]
```

Comment: `["AA", "Ab", "AB", "Aa"]` should be sorted how? Just to be sure?

Comment: cant get you. Generally the array needs to be sorted first with upper case words and then followed by lower case words in alphabet order.

Comment: The uppercase test needs to be done only in the first letter or not, that's my question.

Comment: With your example, if you add "AlphA" and "alphA1" to your test values, where should they be in the sorted result?

Comment: Yes upper case test needs to be done for the first letter

Comment: First AlphaA then alphaA1
As we need the uppercase sorted first and then lowercase based on alphabetical order

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/233564/discussion-between-ganesh-and-larme).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try [NSString.CompareOptions.literal](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsstring/compareoptions/1412961-literal) out -

> Exact character-by-character equivalence.

```
let names = ["Alpha", "alpha1", "Alpha1", "alpha2", "beta", "Beta1"]
let sortedNames = names.sorted { $0.compare($1, options: [.literal]) == .orderedAscending }
```

This gives you -

```
▿ 6 elements
  - 0 : "Alpha"
  - 1 : "Alpha1"
  - 2 : "Beta1"
  - 3 : "alpha1"
  - 4 : "alpha2"
  - 5 : "beta"
```

As you can see, it will sort precisely based on char-by-char basis. However it will still keep all UPPERCASE ones at the start and lowercase ones in the end.

---

What you need is a custom implementation where you have the full control on comparison algorithm -

#### Code

```
extension Array where Element == String {
    
    /// This is a very limited logic that compares values based on following two distinctions only -
    ///
    /// 1. Letters - See docs for `Character.isLetter`
    /// - "A" (U+0041 LATIN CAPITAL LETTER A)
    /// - "é" (U+0065 LATIN SMALL LETTER E, U+0301 COMBINING ACUTE ACCENT)
    /// - "ϴ" (U+03F4 GREEK CAPITAL THETA SYMBOL)
    /// - "ڈ" (U+0688 ARABIC LETTER DDAL)
    /// - "日" (U+65E5 CJK UNIFIED IDEOGRAPH-65E5)
    /// - "ᚨ" (U+16A8 RUNIC LETTER ANSUZ A)
    ///
    /// 2. Whole Numbers - See docs for `Character.isWholeNumber`
    /// - "1" (U+0031 DIGIT ONE) => 1
    /// - "५" (U+096B DEVANAGARI DIGIT FIVE) => 5
    /// - "๙" (U+0E59 THAI DIGIT NINE) => 9
    /// - "万" (U+4E07 CJK UNIFIED IDEOGRAPH-4E07) => 10_000
    ///
    func sortedAlphabeticallyNumericallyCaseSensitive() -> [String] {
        return self.sorted { s1, s2 in
            for (i1, c1) in s1.enumerated() {
                let i2 = s2.index(s2.startIndex, offsetBy: i1)
                if i2 < s2.endIndex {
                    let c2: Character = s2[i2]
                    
                    /// 1. Support for `Letters`
                    if c1.isLetter, let c1Int = c1.asciiValue,
                       c2.isLetter, let c2Int = c2.asciiValue {
                        if c1Int == c2Int {
                            continue
                        }
                        if (c1.isUppercase && c2.isUppercase) || (c1.isLowercase && c2.isLowercase) {
                            return c1Int < c2Int
                        }
                        else if c1.isUppercase {
                            return c1Int <= (c2.uppercased().first?.asciiValue ?? 0)
                        }
                        else {
                            return (c1.uppercased().first?.asciiValue ?? 0) < c2Int
                        }
                    }
                    
                    /// 2. Support for Whole Numbers
                    else if c1.isWholeNumber, let c1NumberValue = c1.wholeNumberValue,
                            c2.isWholeNumber, let c2NumberValue = c2.wholeNumberValue {
                        if c1NumberValue == c2NumberValue {
                            continue
                        }
                        return c1NumberValue < c2NumberValue
                    }
                    
                    /// 1x2
                    else if c1.isWholeNumber, c2.isLetter {
                        return true
                    }
                    else if c1.isLetter, c2.isWholeNumber {
                        return false
                    }
                    
                    /// You are welcome to add any other criteria
                }
                else {
                    return s1.count < s2.count
                }
            }
            return s1.count < s2.count
        }
    }
```

#### Usage

```
let names = ["alpha58", "Zebra", "Alpha", "alpha55", "alpha5", "alpha", "ALPHA", "alpha1", "Alpha1", "alpha2", "beta", "Beta1"]
let sortedNames = names.sortedAlphabeticallyNumericallyCaseSensitive()

(lldb) po sortedNames
▿ 12 elements
  - 0 : "ALPHA"
  - 1 : "Alpha"
  - 2 : "Alpha1"
  - 3 : "alpha"
  - 4 : "alpha1"
  - 5 : "alpha2"
  - 6 : "alpha5"
  - 7 : "alpha55"
  - 8 : "alpha58"
  - 9 : "Beta1"
  - 10 : "beta"
  - 11 : "Zebra"
```

#### Notes

1. It does not limit the comparison to just the first character. It keeps comparing two strings char-by-char until it has a conclusion on which one comes first.
2. This will most likely have performance issues while sorting large lists. it's best that this sorting happens on a background thread so UI doesn't freeze.

---

#### Update

More often than not, in the apps we are dealing with record types that contain these string values. For example a `Person` record.

Above implementation can be adapted to work with any record type like following -

```
struct Person {
    let id: String
    let name: String
    init(id: String = UUID().uuidString, name: String) {
        self.id = id
        self.name = name
    }
}

extension Array where Element == Person {
    
    func sortedAlphabeticallyNumericallyCaseSensitive() -> [Element] {
        return self.sorted { p1, p2 in
            let s1 = p1.name
            let s2 = p2.name
            /// same as above implementation
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Arun. It works. Your answer was in detail and helped a lot.

Comment: @tarun throws error `Missing return in closure expected to return 'Bool'`

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't find a simple answer but this two-step solution seems to work

First make a dictionary grouped by the first character in upper case

```
let dictionary = Dictionary(grouping: names, by: { String($0.prefix(1)).uppercased()})
```

Then sort the values first and then the keys and use `flatMap` to create a new array from the sorted values

```
let sorted = dictionary
    .mapValues { $0.sorted() }
    .sorted(by: { $0.key < $1.key })
    .flatMap({ $0.value})
```

---

*Previous version of this answer removed*

Answer (score 1):

With a custom `sort()`, this should do the trick:

```
let sorted = names.sorted {
    if $0.isUppercasePrefixed == $1.isUppercasePrefixed || $0.prefix(1).localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare($1.prefix(1)) != .orderedSame {
        return $0.localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare($1) == .orderedSame
    } else {
        return $0.isUppercasePrefixed
    }

}
print("Sorted: \(sorted)")
```

With the help of:

```
extension String {
    var isUppercasePrefixed: Bool {
        return first?.isUppercase ?? false
    }
}
```

Output:

$> sorted: ["Alpha", "Alpha1", "alpha1", "alpha2", "Beta1", "beta"]

I've simplified the cases, but here's the logic:

If both starts with an uppercase 
-> "normal compare" (ie: `$0.localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare($1) == .orderedSame`)
If both starts with a lowercase 
-> "normal compare" (ie: `$0.localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare($1) == .orderedSame`)
If one start with a lower case and the other starts with a lowercase
-> if it's the same letter: prioritize the one with the uppercase (ie `$0.isUppercasePrefixed`)
-> if they both have different starting letters: -> "normal compare" (ie: `$0.localizedCompare($1) == .orderedSame`)

We see there there a multiple conditions where the result would be the same, and after factorization of them, we got the result in the code.

Comment: whats `.orderedSame` its throwing error

Comment: It's `ComparisonResult.orderedSame`, and it doesn't throw an error on my end.